# JS offset different results

Tags: jquery, position, offset

I am working on a smaller webpage (onepage) and I stumbled upon something very strange. I am trying to get the exact offset top position of a alement. As you can se at the screenshot, the first result is logged via:

```
console.log($('section#members')[0].offsetTop);
```

And second result is just a log of:

```
console.log($('section#members'));
```

The second result is giving the correct result and the first is wrong. However when I try to get the second result(2), via the first code example it outputs the wrong result.
Any idear why this is happening?

Regards, Simon[image]

Comment: are you sure that's inspecting `$('section#band')`?  Looks like it's inspecting `$('section#members')`

Comment: sorry, that was unfurtunately just a typo... Still same problem :/:)

Comment: if you `console.log($('section#members')[0].offsetTop)` it again, does it go back to `1605`?

Answer (score 1):

I found out at last that the issue did happend because the way elements was loaded. In this case the js log was called before css stuff was rendered, so I guess that was the issue. Hope this helps somebody else :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but I had the same problem and it's interesting how the result is off by `200px` on both cases. But like you said it's a loading problem.